# Split row into multiple columns choosing just certain values from a row and dropping the rest

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like this:

```
name      surname     device
anna      smith       Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/603.1.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/14E304
petr      lebowski    Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0
eveline   jones       Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0.1; SAMSUNG SM-G903F Build/MMB29K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) SamsungBrowser/5.4 Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

My goal is to split these rows into multiple columns and to choose just certain values to create new columns so that a new dataframe looks like this:

```
name      surname     device        column1     column2               column3
anna      smith       as in df      iPhone CPU  iPhone OS 10_3_1      Mac OS X 
petr      lebowski    as in df      Macintosh   Intel Mac OS X 10.6   rv:48.0
eveline   jones       as in df      Linux       Android 6.0.1         SAMSUNG SM-G903F Build/MMB29K
```

So basically I want to choose just certain values from these rows: just those in brackets separated by ';'.

I know how to split it a symbol by symbol:

```
def split_it(string):
    return re.findall(r"[\w']+|[.,!?;]", string)
```

as well as how to create a new column with split rows:

```
df['device'].str[1:-1].str.split(',', expand=True)
```

but how to choose just certain values and create columns with them no idea...

Comment: You example doesn't quite work; the first row only has a single `;` between the parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a better regex:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\((.+?); (.+?)(?: like|;) (.+?)\)")
new_columns = df.device.str.extract(pattern, expand=False)
```

You can even have them prenamed:

```
new_columns = df.Device.str.extract(r"\((?P<column1>.+?); (?P<column2>.+?)(?: like|;) (?P<column3>.+?)\)", expand=False)
```

Then, you simply have to `join` it back with the rest of the data:

```
df = df.join(new_columns)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could leverage the newer [**`regex` module**](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/) and some programming logic:

```
import pandas as pd, regex as re

# your df here

rx = re.compile(r'(?:\G(?!\A)|^[^()]*\()([^();]+);?')

def getter(col):
    # default empty dict
    empty = {'column1': '', 'column2': '', 'column3': ''}

    # generate results with a comprehension
    matches = {'column{}'.format(idx): val 
        for idx, val in enumerate(rx.findall(col), 1)}
    return pd.Series(dict(empty, **matches))

df[["column1", "column2", "column3"]] = df["device"].apply(getter)
print(df[["column1", "column2", "column3"]])
```

This yields for your example

```
     column1                              column2  \
0     iPhone   CPU iPhone OS 10_3_1 like Mac OS X   
1  Macintosh                  Intel Mac OS X 10.6   
2      Linux                        Android 6.0.1   

                          column3  
0                                  
1                         rv:48.0  
2   SAMSUNG SM-G903F Build/MMB29K
```

---

### Explanation

While surely not perfect, the idea is to match `;` inside `(` and `)`. Here, `\G` is needed which matches where the last match stopped:

```
(?:           # non-capturing group
    \G(?!\A)  # match where the last match stopped, not the beginning
    |         # or
    ^[^()]*\( # find the first (
)
(             # capture group 1
    [^();]+   # anything not (, ) or ; at least once
)
;?            # semicolon optionally
```

Afterwards, the function `getter` returns a new `pd.Series()` which will be saved in `df`. The logic inside `getter()` overwrites an empty dict.

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aO5jch/2).